# Properties file to excel file

Tags: java, apache-poi

We have a property file, I want to get data from the property file in an excel workbook! The problem is, I have only one property file, in that, almost all data is there, now I need to filter that data and store it on different sheets in an excel workbook! Is it possible? I need 5 sheets, I created 5 sheets, I splitted the property file into String array! The problem is, I need to write same code 5 times! Can anyone help me out?
I'm using XSSFWorkbook!

```
  while ((str = br.readLine()) != null) {
    fullData = fullData + "\n" + str;
  }
  String[] sheetData = fullData.split("//Split");
  int rows = 0, cols = 0;
  for (String details : sheetData) {
    String name = "", value = "";
    if (details.contains("Home Page")) {
      lines = details.split("\n");
      for (int j = 0; j < lines.length; j++) {
        if (lines[j].contains("=")) {
          int lrows = sheet1.getLastRowNum();
          row = sheet1.createRow(lrows + 1);
          name = lines[j].substring(0, lines[j].indexOf("="));
          value = lines[j].substring(lines[j].indexOf("=") + 1);
          for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            col = row.createCell(cols);
            col.setCellValue(name);
            col = row.createCell(cols + 1);
            col.setCellValue(value);  
          }  
          cols = 0;
        }  
      }
    }
    else if (details.contains("ManualTest") || details.contains("Expand camera")) {

      lines = details.split("\n");
      for (int j = 0; j < lines.length; j++) {
        if (lines[j].contains("=")) {
          int lrows = sheet3.getLastRowNum();
          row = sheet3.createRow(lrows + 1);
          name = lines[j].substring(0, lines[j].indexOf("="));
          value = lines[j].substring(lines[j].indexOf("=") + 1);
          for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            col = row.createCell(cols);
            col.setCellValue(name);
            col = row.createCell(cols + 1);
            col.setCellValue(value);

          }
          rows++;
          cols = 0;
        }  
      }
    }
  }
```

This is for 2 sheets, same like this, I have 5 sheets! I used one line //split, by which I'm splitting the data into sheets!

Comment: You'll have to show us what you've tried and what you are converting to excel.

Answer (score 1):

> The problem is, I need to write same code 5 times!

You do not have to write the entire code five times, if you use a method:

```
private void fillSheet(String[] lines, HSSFSheet sheet) {
    for (int j = 0; j < lines.length; j++) {
        if (lines[j].contains("=")) {
            int cols = 0;
            int lrows = sheet.getLastRowNum();
            int row = sheet.createRow(lrows + 1);
            String name = lines[j].substring(0, lines[j].indexOf("="));
            String value = lines[j].substring(lines[j].indexOf("=") + 1);
            for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
                HSSFCell col = row.createCell(cols);
                col.setCellValue(name);
                col = row.createCell(cols + 1);
                col.setCellValue(value);
            }
            cols = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

and use it like this:

```
while ((str = br.readLine()) != null) {
    fullData = fullData + "\n" + str;
}
String[] sheetData = fullData.split("//Split");
for (String details : sheetData) {
      String[] lines = details.split("\n");
      if (details.contains("Home Page")) {
        fillSheet(lines, sheet1);
    }
    else if (details.contains("ManualTest") || details.contains("Expand camera")) {
        fillSheet(lines, sheet3);
    }
      // else if ....
}
```